# Elastic Potential Energy Of Elastic Wire: Two contradictory methods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, elasticity, stress-strain

> Suppose a wire of length $L$, cross sectional area $A$, density $\rho$
> and Young's Modulus $Y$ is suspended at one of its ends from a
> ceiling, then find its total elastic potential energy due to its own
> weight.

**Method 1**: We treat the wire as a spring, thus its potential energy will be $\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$ where $k=\frac{YA}{L}$. To find the extension $x$, we can use the following argument: Take an element of length $dy$ at a distance $y$ from the free end of the wire. Writing Hooke's Law for this element
$$\frac{F}{A}=Y\frac{\delta y}{dy}$$
where $F$ is the load on the elemental part of wire and $\delta y$ is elemental change in length. $F=\rho yAg$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\rho g}{Y} \int_{0}^{L} ydy=\int_{0}^{x} \delta y$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{\rho g}{Y}\times \frac{L^{2}}{2}=\frac{\rho gL^{2}}{2Y}$$
$$\Rightarrow U=\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{YA}{L}\times \frac{\rho^{2}g^{2}L^{4}}{4Y^{2}}=\frac{\rho^{2}g^{2}AL^{3}}{8Y}$$

**Method 2**: Using the definition of energy density in an elastic wire
$$\frac{dU}{dV}=\frac{1}{2}\psi\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\psi^{2}}{Y}$$
where $\psi$ is Stress and $\epsilon$ is strain. $\psi=\frac{F}{A}=\rho yg$ on the element from the argument in method 1. When we use the above equation for the element described in method 1, we get
$$\frac{dU}{dV}=\frac{1}{2Y}\times \psi^{2}=\frac{1}{2Y}\times \rho^{2}y^{2}g^{2}$$
$$dU=\frac{\rho^{2}g^{2}Ay^{2}dy}{2Y}$$
$$\Rightarrow U=\frac{\rho^{2}g^{2}A}{2Y}\int_{0}^{L} y^{2}dy=\frac{\rho^{2}g^{2}AL^{3}}{6Y}$$

We get two different values for the total elastic potential energy. Please provide an explanation as to how this discrepancy comes about and point out the mistake in any of the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Method 1**: We treat the wire as a spring, thus its potential energy will be $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$

This equation is derived for an end-loaded massless ideal spring. Instead, you have a massive spring undergoing a distributed gravitational body force. Your second method is appropriate for this problem.